# Error C2275 while creating a COM smart-pointer within "if" statement

Tags: c++, com, smart-pointers

Why can't i

```
if (IUnknownPtr p = anotherComPtr) {} //error C2275: 'IUnknownPtr' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

while i can

```
if (int* a = anotherPointer) {}
```

`IUnknownPtr` is defined throught `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IUnknown, __uuidof(IUnknown))` (like any others smart pointers i use)

How can i create a com smartptr within `if` statement and verify is it valid or not? Thank you.

I use VS 2008

p.s. This is not about is it good way of coding or not, it's about `error C2275`.

Comment: This is weird. Which version of Visual C++ do you use?

Comment: Why are you not creating the pointer outside the if? And check for validity in the if? Or is the obvious in COM context? (No experience)

Comment: Tried on VS2k8 and VS2k10 - works just fine.

Comment: @PoweRoy: i think my way if more ellegant - to automatically release a pointer after ``if`` statement end. I wouldn't like to wrap such construction into additional ``{}``.

Comment: @sharptooth: i know it must works fine, but doesn't. This is why i've posted the question. Anyway, thank you for checking.

Comment: The if() statement expression is not a scope block.  So there's no good way for the compiler to figure out exactly when the smart pointer needs to be destructed.  This is simply invalid C++ code.

Comment: @HansPassant: 6.4 _A name introduced by a declaration in a condition (either introduced by the type-specifier-seq or the
declarator of the condition) is in scope from its point of declaration until the end of the substatements controlled
by the condition._

Comment: I can only think the error isn't in the line you've posted.  Maybe a typo in your use of the macro...?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your compiler error in vs2008 in the small program below. There is likely to be something different in your include files, preprocessor definitions or compiler options which is giving you different behaviour.

Can you declare a simple variable of type IUnknownPtr outside an if statement?

Can you create a new project using the code below without the error?

Does either of the following compile OK?

```
if (NULL == (IUnknownPtr ptr = someOtherPtr)) {
}

IUnknownPtr foo;
bool b(foo);
```

The error suggests the compiler can see a definition of IUnknownPtr but can't interpret the result of the assignment of an IUnknownPtr as a bool.

operator = should return IUnknownPtr& (the object that's been assigned to). _com_ptr_t defines operator bool(). Are your _COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF generating references to _com_ptr_t or some other type? You can easily find out by temporarily dumping out the preprocessor output (properties/C++/preprocessor/preprocess to a file)

```
#include <comdef.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IUnknownPtr foo;
    IUnknown* foo2 = NULL;

    if (IUnknownPtr foo3 = foo) {
        // do something
    }

    if (IUnknownPtr foo4 = foo2) {
        // do something
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I vaugely remember something about MSDEV not following the C++ specs when it came to declaring a variable inside an if statement (or it might have been a for loop?).

It should have been destructed at the end of the brackets but it was not.

Possibly this is a throwback to that - have you tried combing the MSDN archives?  It seems more like a quirk than intentional behaviour, unless (as another poster commented) you have misunderstood what is happening.

Can you post the actual code, complete with surrounding function?

Comment: You are correct, but it was the for statement, and it's been fixed at some point (it's definitely fixed in VS2010).  The 'if' should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since this compiles for me just fine on VS 2010, I'm going to assume maybe you didn't `#include <comdef.h>` and/or `#include <comdefsp.h>`.